# Angular2 stop propagation hover event on child elements, which replays animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I made an hover efect in angular way, but I have trouble with propagation hover on child element, on child elements. When Hower touch button, animation is replayed.

When I use mouseenter() I have lose scope, and animation is played on all elements.

ANIMATION:

```
animations: [
        trigger('albumState', [
            state('inactive', style({
                bottom: '0px',
                opacity: 0
            })),
            state('active', style({
                bottom: '20%',
                opacity: 1
            })),
            transition('inactive => active', animate('200ms ease-in')),
            transition('active => inactive', animate('200ms ease-in'))
        ])
    ]
```

HTML:

```
<masonry-brick 
        *ngFor="let album of categoryAlbums | orderBy: ['activeAlbums']" 
        (click)="goDetail(album)" 
        class="album__item" 
        id="album" 
        (mouseover)="active(album, $event)" 
        (mouseout)="inactive(album, $event)">
            <div class="album__item--cover-container">
                <img class="album__item--cover" [src]="this.getCoverPhoto(album.cover)" alt="album cover">
                <div class="album__item--story">
                    <div class="album__item--title">
                        {{ album.title | uppercase }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="album__item--description" [@albumState]="album.state">
                        <div class="item-desc">
                            {{ album.desc }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="item-button">
                            <input class="btn btn-success album__item--button" type="button" value="Enter">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</masonry-brick>
```

METHODS:

```
active(album: Album, event: Event) { 
        let target = $('.album__item');
        let child = $('.item-button');
        album.state = 'active';
        console.log("ENTERED MOUSENTER", album);
    }
inactive(album: Album, event: Event) { 
        let target = $('.album__item');
        album.state = 'inactive';
        console.log("ENTERED LEAVE", album);    
    }
```

As I said, if I use in methods `target.mouseenter(()=>{[...]})` I lose my scope and Animation is played on all masonry blocks.

My question is: How can I prevent replay animation, when hover is propagate on button: ".item-button". For claryfication, I'v set CSS "`pointer-event`" for `none` in parent `div` with class `.album__item--description`, but button must be active.